# How do I prevent "patch" from creating backup files with a tilde at the end?

Tags: bash, patch

I am running `diff` and `patch` like this:

```bash
diff --unified --ignore-space-change old.txt new.txt > changed.patch
patch --version-control=none third.txt changed.patch
```

The `--version-control=none` is supposed to prevent `patch` from creating a `third.txt.orig` file (which it does).

However, it creates a file called `third.txt.~1~` instead.

All the hunks succeeded and the `SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX` environment variable is empty.

The `--posix` option creates the `third.orig` file.

I don't mind if the `third.rej` file is created if there are problems.

I am using Git Bash with GNU patch 2.7.6.

Comment: I can't find a manual that says that `none` is a valid option argument to `--version-control`. Is the goal to get `patch` to not create a backup of the original file at all?

Comment: The FreeBSD version documents it https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=patch It seems to work even though I am using GNU. The goal *is* to get `patch` to not create a backup of the original file at all

Comment: I'm guessing GNU `patch` treats `none` as `numeric` since it starts with `n`, or something, it is obviously not treating it the same as FreeBSD `patch` does (which is not what you're using anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short: use [`--no-backup-if-mismatch`](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Backups.html):

> Normally, ***patch*** creates a backup file if the patch does not exactly match the original input file, because in that case the original data might not be recovered if you undo the patch with ‘**`patch -R`**’ (see Applying Reversed Patches). However, when conforming to POSIX, patch does not create backup files by default. See patch and the [POSIX Standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/patch.html).
>
> The **`--backup`** (-b) option causes patch to make a backup file regardless of whether the patch matches the original input. The **`--backup-if-mismatch`** option causes patch to create backup files for mismatches files; this is the default when not conforming to POSIX. The **`--no-backup-if-mismatch`** option causes patch to not create backup files, even for mismatched patches; this is the default when conforming to POSIX.

(That "conforming" takes some interpretation which is not apparent in the The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018).